# Using Rx in Silverlight for WCF calls doesn't work with TakeUntil

Tags: silverlight, wcf, system.reactive

I have the following bit of code to set up my Rx hookups:

Event related definitions:

```
    public class QueryEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public SomeParametersType SomeParameters
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public object QueryContext
        {
                     get;
            set;
        }
    };

    public delegate void QueryDelegate(object sender, QueryEventArgs e);

    public event QueryDelegate QueryEvent;
```

Initialization:

```
            queryObservable = Observable.FromEvent<QueryEventArgs>(this, "QueryEvent");
            queryObservable.Subscribe((e) =>
            {
                tbQueryProgress.Text = "Querying... ";
                client.QueryAsync(e.EventArgs.SomeParameters, e.EventArgs.QueryContext);
            });

            queryCompletedObservable = from e in Observable.FromEvent<QueryCompletedEventArgs>(client, "QueryCompleted").TakeUntil(queryObservable) select e;

            queryCompletedObservable.Subscribe((e) =>
                {
                    tbQueryProgress.Text = "Ready";
                    SilverlightClientService_QueryCompleted(e.Sender, e.EventArgs);
                },
                (Exception ex) =>
                {
                    SetError("Query error: " + ex);
                }
            );
```

"client" is the WCF client and everything else is fairly self-explanatory.

The "TakeUntil" is there to stop the user stomping on himself when doing a new query while in the middle of a currently running one. However, while the code works if I remove the "TakeUntil" clause, if I put it in, the query is never completed.

Is this the correct pattern? If so, am I doing something wrong?

Cheers,
-Tim

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TakeUntil` terminates the subscription when a value is received from its argument, so your first `queryObservable` starts up the query but also terminates the subscription to the complete events.

The simpler solution is to setup an `IObservable` around your actual query, and then use `Switch` to ensure that only one query runs at a time.

```
public static class ClientExtensions
{
    public static IObservable<QueryCompletedEventArgs> QueryObservable(
        this QueryClient client,
        object[] someParameters, object queryContext)
    {
       return Observable.CreateWithDisposable<QueryCompletedEventArgs>(observer =>
       {
            var subscription = Observable.FromEvent<QueryCompletedEventArgs>(
                    h => client.QueryCompleted += h,
                    h => client.QueryCompleted -= h
                )
                .Subscribe(observer);

            client.QueryAsync(someParameters, queryContext);

            return new CompositeDisposable(
                subscription,
                Disposable.Create(() => client.Abort())
            );
        });
    }
}
```

Then you can do this:

```
queryObservable = Observable.FromEvent<QueryEventArgs>(this, "QueryEvent");

queryObservable
    .Select(query => client.QueryObservable(
        query.EventArgs.SomeParameters, 
        query.EventArgs.QueryContext
    ))
    .Switch()
    .Subscribe(queryComplete =>
    {
        tbQueryProgress.Text = "Ready";
        // ... etc
    });
```

This sets up one continuous flow, whereby each "Query" event starts a query which emits the complete event from that query. New queries automatically teriminate the previous query (if possible) and start a new one.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick answer, but I'm not sure I understand your warning... If new queries terminate prior queries with the "Switch", how would you get a case where there are multiple queries?

Comment: @Tim - Unsubscribing from a "FromEvent" does not prevent the event from being raised, so the "Complete" event from the first query is still raised when it completes. When you subscribe to complete again (for the second query), you'll receive the complete from the first query and then again for the second.

Comment: @Tim - What is the method signature of `QueryAsync`?

Comment: @Tim - I've updated the example so that it calls `Abort` to prevent the previous Query request when it starts a new one. Also, I've updated the "Completed" event subscription to be strongly typed (no string reference to the event)

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. I haven't seen the types of things you are doing in the examples I've seen.QueryAsync just takes a single parameter of type "SomeParametersType" in my original message. Rx is confusing! I'm on a deadline so I went with a more traditional approach for now - going to come back to Rx and do it properly later.

Comment: Sorry, I was copying QueryAsync from your original example. I can update my code snippet if you tell me the signature for QueryAsync